# Running Redis with Docker (performance issue)

Tags: redis, docker

Has anyone else seen performance issues with running Redis in a Docker container environment?

Here's what I've noticed...
Setup A: Local machine, traditional Redis install
Setup B: Local machine, using canonical Redis image https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/redis/

I've got an identical HTTP server on my local machine that fires as fast as the request/response cycle will allow.

Observations:
- A can sustain approximately 2X the throughput of B.
- B performs identical to A when you benchmark (from within the container)

So, this leads me to believe that B is slower than A because of a networking issue: i.e. the networking relays introduced by running software in a virtualized environment are creating significant performance issues...

Just wondering if anyone else has noticed anything like this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Docker's default networking option, `--net=bridge` introduces overhead due to NAT packet rewriting, noticeable with high packet rates.

Network performance can be improved by using `--net=host`, instructing Docker to not create a separate network stack for the container, allowing full access to the host network interfaces.

This option should be used carefully though, as it lets container processes open low-numbered ports like any other root process, and access local network services like D-bus, which can lead to processes in the container being able to do unexpected things.

In short: If you know what you are running inside the container it is safe. If you suspect unwanted or aggressive behavior - do not do it.

Comment: @joshula So the problem fixed? The throughput are same now? Just curious. thanks

Comment: going to run a few experiments today. will report back.

Comment: @joshula it seems your experiments took 3 years

Comment: @joshula it seems your experiment took 6 years

Comment: I've just tested with --net=host, I get 34K RPS, without I get 16KRPS, native redis install without docker: 40k RPS

Comment: @joshula it seems your experiment took 7 years

Comment: @joshula it seems your experiment took 8 years

Comment: @joshula it seems your experiment took 9 years

Comment: @joshula it seems your experiment took 10 years